# Ошибка: Index exceeds array dimensions

Tags: массивы, матрицы, matlab

Ошибка: Index exceeds array dimensions. Index value 2 exceeds valid range [1-1] of array b.
Добрый вечер. Описываю некий код в workspace. При этом все работает, все отлично считает.
Пытаюсь этот же код записать в блок simulink-а "MUTLAB FUNCTION". Здесь же выдал кучу ошибок. Довела до одной ошибки, но не знаю, как ее исправить. 
На вход функции поступает массив размером 40001*1. На выходе должен быть массив размером 25*30. Ошибка возникает на строчке B(j,k) = b(i)
Ниже приведен данный код.

```
function y  = fcn(u)
%реальный сигнал 
j=1; 
k=1;
N=1333; %количество отсчетов
b=u(:,1);
B1 = zeros(1333,30);  
B2= zeros(600,300); 
B=zeros(1333,30);
for i=1:1:39990 %цикл для разделения на 30 частей. в отдельности применено fft
 B(j,k) = b(i);
 j=j+1;
 if mod(i,1333)==0 
   B0=abs(fft(B,N));% Амплитуды преобразования Фурье сигнала
   B1=2*B0./N; % Нормировка спектра по амплитуде
   B1(1)=B1(1)/2; % Нормировка постоянной составляющей в спектре
   k=k+1; 
   j=1;
 end 
end
for i=1:1:600
    for k=1:1:30
    B2(i,k)=B1(i,k);
    end
end
i=1;
p=1;
B3= zeros(30,600);  
%цикл для разделения на 25 частей строки каждого столбца
for k=1:1:30 %кол-во столбцов в В2
    i=0;
     for j=1:1:600 %кол-во строк в B2
         i=i+1;
         B3(i,p)=B2(j,k);         
         if i==24
             p=p+1; %то что порезали добавляем в новые столбцы , т.е. получится 25*30 столбцов
             i=0;
         end  
     end
end
%среднее значение в 25-и частях
B4=mean(B3.',2);
p=0;
k=1;
B5=zeros(25,30);  
for i=1:1:length(B4) %запись в конечный массив 25*30
p=p+1;
B5(p,k) = B4(i);
if mod(i,25)==0 
k=k+1;
p=0;
end
end
B7 = zeros(30,1);  
%Нормировка по максимуму
B6=max(B5.',[],2);
B7(30,1)=1;
B7(:,1)=1;
B8=B7./B6;
B8=B8';
B9 = zeros(25,30);  
for i=1:1:30 
B9(:,i)=B5(:,i)*B8(i); 
end
y=B9;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Не смог вопроизвести ошибку, MATLAB 2016a. Используемый мной минимальный пример:

```
B=zeros(1333,30);
j=1;
k=1;
for i=1:1:39990
    B(j,k) = i; j=j+1;
    if mod(i,1333)==0
        k=k+1;
        j=1;
    end,
end
```

Единственное, что могу подсказать - не используйте i и j в качестве имен переменных, в матлабе они означают корень из -1. Если после изменения имён счетчиков осталась ошибка, укажите версию матлаба и ОС, будем думать дальше.